# SCCM Application Discovery Won't Run

Tags: sccm, application, discovery

I have a strange issue with a single CM client machine, the application discovery will not run.  I go to control panel and try to manually run the action but the logs show nothing new in appdiscover.log.  Everything seems ok including software updates and end point protection updates.

The only thing that has happened to this machine (which happens to be my machine) is that I moved it to a new OU.

I have tried removing my machine from CM and uninstalling using the 2003 Toolkit ccmclean.exe /all command.  Then re-installing the client manually and rediscovering my machine.  It populates in CM, adds to the correct groups, refreshes policies, gets end point protection information but still won't do any app discovery.

Does anyone know of any troubleshooting to try from here?

Using SCCM 2012.  A couple of weeks ago everything was fine.